Use ComboBox as TextBox in userform
I created a userform with multiple fields (all of them are text boxes). In the first field I indicate the research criteria. Upon clicking the "Search" button, the macro looks in column A of the table and if it finds the value, it displays the other elements located on the same line in the other text boxes. This is a sample of the code I use for diplaying:
Me.TextBox1.Text = fCell.Offset(0,23).Value

I wanted to modify the form so I can use it to update the table, so I replaced some text boxes with combo boxes. These combo boxes have predefined values established in the Userform_Initialize section of the code.
Now, when I open the empty user form, write the value I need to look for and click on "Search", I receive an error message at the line
Me.ComboBox1.Value = fCell.Offset(0, 23).Value

Even when I use Me.ComboBox1.Text, the result is the same.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Remember, the code worked flawlessly when using only text boxes.
(Sorry, I cannot post the entire code here as it is on my work computer and I can't copy-paste it, nor sending it by email to an external email address).
